# Using states to manage onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, state, touch-event

I am making a single screen application of a simple logic circuit. I am using `onTouchEvent` to handle user interactions. I am using `ACTION_UP`, `ACTION_MOVE`, & `ACTION_DOWN` right now, but this only allows me to use one gesture. I want to be able to selection an option in my UI, such as "AND" gate. I want to use one touch to select what I want to do, then the next touch to place the gate on the screen. Instead, my `onTouchEvent` only allows me to touch the component I want and I have to keep my finger on the screen to drag it to the location I want to place it. This is not want I want.

I've tried researching how to implement some sort of state variable to allow `onTouchEvent` to wait for the next touch, but I don't think I correctly understand how to implement it.

```java
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("Debugging", "In onTouchEvent");

        if((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Touch.horizontalTouched = (int)motionEvent.getX()/ grid.getBlockSize();
            Touch.verticalTouched = (int)motionEvent.getY()/ grid.getBlockSize();
            whatWasTouched = whatWasTouched(Touch.horizontalTouched, Touch.verticalTouched);

        }else if((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            //do nothing, finger is moving on screen
        }
        else if((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Touch.secondHorizontalTouch = (int)motionEvent.getX()/ grid.getBlockSize();
            Touch.secondVerticalTouch = (int)motionEvent.getY()/ grid.getBlockSize();
            placeComponent();
            draw();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I expect my first touch on the screen to be able to select an option, ex: "AND", "OR", "NOT", "SWITCH", "EDIT", etc. and then my second touch completes the desired action. I also want to be able to touch a component I placed on the screen and then touch another component so I can wire them together.

Answer (score 0):

By default, event listeners in Android are for waiting - you don't have to provide any delay.

Simply set the onTouchEvent(...) listener on the ImageView and show the first bitmap. When the ImageView is touched, show the next bitmap and so on. All you have to do is keep a count of how many touches there have been in order to know which image to show (image 1, 2, 3, 4 etc).

Example...

```
public class LoadImage extends Activity {

int imageNumber = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_image);

    //get an image and create a bitmap from it

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        imageNumber++;
        switch (imageNumber) {
            case 2:
                // show image 2
                break;
            case 3:
                // show image 3
                break;
            ...
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking to do. There are other functionalities I want to do in my program that requires an initial touch and a destination touch. Im not just drawing images using touch.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by using a static class that will handle the state of my touches.

```java
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("Debugging", "In onTouchEvent");
        if (placeState.getState() == false) {
            if ((motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Touch.horizontalTouched = (int) motionEvent.getX() / grid.getBlockSize();
                Touch.verticalTouched = (int) motionEvent.getY() / grid.getBlockSize();
                whatWasTouched = whatWasTouched(Touch.horizontalTouched, Touch.verticalTouched);
                if(whatWasTouched.equals("DELETE")){
                    visualComponents.clear();
                    logicalComponents.clear();
                }
                placeState.toggleState();//sets to true
                draw();
            }

        }else if (placeState.getState() == true) {
            Touch.secondHorizontalTouch = (int) motionEvent.getX() / grid.getBlockSize();
            Touch.secondVerticalTouch = (int) motionEvent.getY() / grid.getBlockSize();
            placeComponent();
            placeState.toggleState();//sets to false
            draw();
        }
        return true;
    }
```